# How do I calculate the percent difference between the 1st and 6th key in a list of dictionaries?

Tags: python, list, pandas, dictionary

I have a pandas df column with a list of dictionaries for each each company name. Like below:

```
company  |  growth_scores
comp xyz | [{u'score': u'198', u'recorded_at': u'2016-09},{u'score': u'190', u'recorded_at': u'2016-08}
```

I understand how to extract the keys and I'm familiar with the pd.apply method but I can't seem to piece together anything that will go row-by-row and perform the calculation. Ultimately, I need to perform a calculation and store the result in a new column, for each company.

The output should look like this:

```
company  |  growth_score_diff
comp xyz |  10%
```

Would love some guidance here!

Comment: What is `1st` and `6th` key?  Is it `score`?

Comment: Incomplete dictionary @Kevin . Possibly this could you understand dictionaries : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3294889/iterating-over-dictionaries-using-for-loops-in-python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say you have the following DataFrame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'company': 'Pandology', 'metrics': [[{'score': 10}, {'score': 20}, {'score': 35}]]})
```

which looks like this:

[image]

To compute a total score, you can `map` the `metrics` column to a new column called `score_total`. To perform the actual calculation, you define a function `calculate_score` which takes a row of `metrics` data as input and outputs a total score value. (*In this case it's just a trivial sum calculation)*

```
def calculate_score(metrics):
    total_score = 0
    for metric in metrics:
        total_score += metric['score']
    return total_score                

df['score_total'] = df['metrics'].map(calculate_score)
```

Now you have a new column containing the result:

[image]

Comment: hey @kmandov thanks for the help here! One issue I'm running into though, is that the scores are actually strings and thus, I can't perform the calc. Is there a way to work around that?

Comment: You need to cast the strings into a numeric value. It can be as simple as: int(metric['score']) if scores are integers. Here is how you can do this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5608702/how-can-i-convert-a-string-to-either-int-or-float-with-priority-on-int